# Prevent QML Property Bindings when QML object isn't visible?

Tags: qt, data-binding, qt4, qml, qt5

I'm working on a QML application that has a lot of property bindings: hundreds of objects are tracked and displayed in different forms like Qt3D/QCanvas.

When I'm on a separate page of the application those property bindings for x/y locations and relative sizes are still happening. How can I stop them? I know I could bind the properties based on whether they're visual or not but that is a lot of unnecessary code:

x: visible ? tracking.location(index).x : 0

I would have to wrap a ton of bindings like that. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Binding`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) element. You can specify target, property, value and condition to activate the binding.

```
Binding on x {
    value: tracking.location(index).x
    when: visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Loader{} and set active property to false. This will disable the whole item.