# How to conditionally disable QML Binding to C++ backend?

Tags: qt, data-binding, qml, qt5

I am working on QML Application for an embedded system that has a lot of property bindings: many sensor data is displayed throughout different pages of the app. Only 1 page is visible at a time.

When I'm on `page 2`, the property bindings for `page 1` are still taking place, even though `visible` is set to `false` on `page 1`. I wish to have QML respond to binding updates, only when the page is `visible`, as it would improve performance.

I have tried using the `Binding` element as described here: [Binding QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) and here: [Prevent QML Property Bindings when QML object isn't visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506359/prevent-qml-property-bindings-when-qml-object-isnt-visible?rq=1), but I've noticed that a binding will still update in QML.

I am wondering if it is possible to completely eliminate the binding, if not on `page 1`.

My code for my attempt at using the Binding Element is attached below. Instead of multiple pages being visible/invisible, I've used a button that toggles a `activated` property.

**main.qml**

```
Rectangle{                                                                               
    x: 280                                                                                         
    y: 20                                                                                          
    width:200                                                                                      
    height:150                                                                                     
    color:"red"                                                                                             
    Text {                                        
        y: 76                                                                                      
        width: 85                                                                                  
        height: 67                                                                                 
        text: "off"                                                  
        Binding on text {                                               
            value: {                                                                               
                // I am surprised to find this prints, regardless of value of controlRect.activated       
                console.log("new value");                                                          
                sensorData.sensorReading.toFixed(1)                                                
            }                                                                                      
            when: controlRect.activated                                                            
        }                                                                                          
    }                                                                                              
}                                                                                                  

Rectangle{                                                                                         
    id: controlRect                                                                                
    x: 20                                                                                          
    y: 20                                                                                          
    width:200                                                                                      
    height:150                                                                                     
    property bool activated: true                                                                  
    color:{                                                                                        
        if (controlRect.activated){                                                                
            "green"                                                                                
        }                                                                                          
        else{                                                                                      
            "yellow"                                                                               
        }                                                                                          
    }                                                                                              

    MouseArea {                                                                                    
        anchors.fill: parent                                                                       
        onClicked: {                                                                               
            console.log("State changed to",!parent.activated);                                     
            parent.activated = !parent.activated                                                   
        }                                                                                          
    }                                                                                         
}
```

**backend.cpp**, instantiated in main.cpp

```
#include "backend.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

Backend::Backend(QQmlApplicationEngine* engine, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    sensorData = new SensorData();
     QQmlContext* ctxt(engine->rootContext());

    // Connecting back end object instances to front end
    ctxt->setContextProperty("sensorData", sensorData);
}
```

**sensordata.h**

```
#ifndef SENSORDATA_H
#define SENSORDATA_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class SensorData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(double sensorReading MEMBER m_sensorReading NOTIFY sensorReadingChanged)

    explicit SensorData(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~SensorData() {}

private:
    double m_sensorReading;
    double temp;
    QTimer m_timer;

signals:
    void sensorReadingChanged();

public slots:
    void slot_updateReading();

};

#endif // SENSORDATA_H
```

**sensordata.cpp**

```
#include "sensordata.h"
#include <QDebug>

SensorData::SensorData(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    // for simulating sensor data
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    m_timer.setInterval(100);
    m_timer.setSingleShot(false);
    QObject::connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &SensorData::slot_updateReading);
    m_timer.start();
}

// simulate my sensor data
void SensorData::slot_updateReading(){
    m_sensorReading = modf(rand() /  100000.0, &temp);
    emit sensorReadingChanged(); // emit for QML binding to update
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it seems the `Binding` is still evaluating the `value` property, but just not assigning it to the `text` property when the `when` clause is false. I would consider this buggy, but maybe there is a rationale behind it.

The solution is to use a `State` as in the following code. This also gives the possibility to state that the value is not being read currently.

```
Rectangle{
    x: 280
    y: 20
    width:200
    height:150
    color:"red"
    Text {
        id: readout
        y: 76
        width: 85
        height: 67
        text: {
            console.log("new value"); //does not print when deactivated
            sensorData.sensorReading.toFixed(1)
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "deactivated"
                when: !controlRect.activated
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: readout
                    text: "off"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```